# TortoiseSVN has an exclamation mark(!) on a file committed under Subversion. I don't know what might be wrong with it. How to check it?

Tags: svn, version-control

So I have this file that has an exclamation mark over it, so I guess there must be something wrong. At first I tried to commit it, but Subversion is telling me there's nothing to commit, so I guess that isn't a problem. Maybe it has something to do with some modification in other branch of this same file?

Isn't there a command over the file I can run that tells me what might be wrong with it? I've run "svn info " but that doesn't seem to contain any relevant info to solve this issue.

Here is a screen shot of the file:

[image]

Comment: In TortoiseSVN, is the exclamation mark over a red or yellow background?  Red would mean uncommitted, while yellow would mean that there are conflicts...

Comment: That's definitively the case I mentioned below in my answer. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sometimes TortoiseSVN's cache does that. It's a known issue due to integration between TortoiseSVN and Windows Explorer.

Solution: Execute a Clean Up (Right-click folder --> Subversion --> Clean Up). That should take care of it.

Comment: Bingo! I had thought that this could have been a Explorer bug, so I restarted my computer, but I didn't know about the clean-up thing. Thanks!

Comment: Clean-up is not related to this, IMO. See my updated answer. It is a TortoiseSVN caching issue. The cache just gets updated when you do cleanup.

Comment: I know. That's stated in my answer. It is just much less work doing a clean up than messing around with `TSVNCache.exe` (which is what I did some time ago)

Answer (score 11):

**Edit after screen shot:**

**Do this :**

> 1) Open task manager and kill
>   TSVNCache.exe
>
> 2) Now refresh on the explorer.

Edit: Ok, if you are seeing nothing to commit, the conflicts would not be the reason.

Generally, that would mean you have conflicts. Open the file and look for the conflicts. You should also see files like

> filename.mine, filename.rrevision1,
>   filename.rrevision2

Those are the original files in your working directory and the corresponding revisions. You can also delete the conflicted file and rename one of these to the filename and delete the others.

If you don't care about the changes you had in your working directory, do a `Revert` and then `Update`

Comment: The file only have the contents I've put there.

Comment: @manojlds, Wouldn't refreshing file explorer (without killing TSVNCache.exe) work?

Answer (score 7):

When I used the default svn-cleanup, the file didn't get updated, but when I selected the following options, it did:

1] Clean up working copy status & 5] Refresh shell overlays

Comment: Refresh shell overlays.That was the ticket for me as well. (This should be the answer) +1

Answer (score 1):

If resolving the conflict or the cleanup command do not work for you then your last option is to do a fresh get from your repository into a new folder.
(I would keep your previous code folder around for a bit until you confirm that the code in your repository is fine.)

Edit after seeing image.
If that is the case and there are no changes to submit try pressing F5. Sometimes windows gets confused. If it annoys you, you can performed what I described above to get it all in the green.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click Working Directory ---> In Tortoise SVN sub Menu --->Select Resolve Option

It will Resolve that issue.